# Change "removed from network questions" to "removed from hot network questions" in HNQ timeline and revision history

Tags: bug, hot-questions, wording, timeline

The [timeline](https://law.stackexchange.com/posts/84605/timeline) and [revisions](https://law.stackexchange.com/posts/84605/revisions) for this [question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/84605) includes:

> became hot network question

And, subsequently:

> removed from network questions

Should the latter entry say "removed from *hot* network questions" for consistency?